# Javascript/jQuery : SCRIPT438 error with IE7/8, any debugging tips?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have a javascript which works perfectly in chrome, FF2/3, and IE9

```
158: drop_area = $('#drop_area');
159: element = ui.helper;
```

however I get the following error in IE7 amd IE8:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method 
dragdrop.js, line 158 character 2
```

My knowledge of IE7's debugging features is pretty limited but it doesn't look like I can really inspect the object in question from the console. Does anyone know what might be going on here or how I can better debug this error

EDIT:
Realized a little bit more context might be helpful

```
function on_element_drop(event, ui){
    drop_area = $('#drop_area');
    element = ui.helper;
```

on_element_drop is a callback method for a jQuery UI droppable 'drop' event

```
/*
 * dragdrop.js
 * Author: Casey Flynn
 * June 10, 2011
 * Global variables available to all functions
 */

//Keeps track of elements present in droppable and corresponding offsets/positions
var base_url = 'http://www.bla/';
var global_positions = new Array();
var current_item_group = 0;
var loaded = new Array();
var preloading = true;
var items = new Array(
    new Array(
        new Array(0, '2-Dollar'), 
        new Array(1, 'Cards'), 
        new Array(2, 'Cheese'),
        new Array(3, 'Coupons'),
        new Array(4, 'DogTags')),
    new Array(
        new Array(5, 'Doodle'), 
        new Array(6, 'Dreamcatcher'), 
        new Array(7, 'Fish'),
        new Array(8, 'Fortune'),
        new Array(9, 'Groucho')),
    new Array(
        new Array(10, 'HandTurkey'), 
        new Array(11, 'Key'), 
        new Array(12, 'Lolipop'),
        new Array(13, 'LotteryTicket'),
        new Array(14, 'Map')),
    new Array(
        new Array(15, 'Napkin'), 
        new Array(16, 'Notepad'), 
        new Array(17, 'OldPhoto'),
        new Array(18, 'Oragami'),
        new Array(19, 'Photo_Baby')),
    new Array(
        new Array(20, 'Photo_DJ'), 
        new Array(21, 'Photo_Dogs'), 
        new Array(22, 'Photo_Moustache'),
        new Array(23, 'Pick'),
        new Array(24, 'RabitsFoot')),
    new Array(
        new Array(25, 'Recipe'), 
        new Array(26, 'Reminder'), 
        new Array(27, 'Ribbon'),
        new Array(28, 'SheetMusic'),
        new Array(29, 'Smiley')),
    new Array(
        new Array(30, 'Spork'),
        new Array(31, 'Tape'),
        new Array(32, 'Ticket'),
        new Array(33, 'USB'),
        new Array(34, 'Viewmaster')
    )
);

/*
 * jQuery 'ready' handler, executes after DOM is ready and 
 * sets draggable/droppable properties of associated elements
 */
$(function(){   
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        loaded[i] = false;
    load_elements(0);

    $('#drop_area').droppable({
        //accept: '.draggable',
        //hoverClass: 'vel_content_active',        
        drop: on_element_drop
    });

    $('#countdown').html((10 - global_positions.length)+'');

});

// preloads an array of images
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        console.log('Preloading ' + this);
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        // Alternatively you could use:
        // (new Image()).src = this;
    });
}


/*
 * Loads the first set of elements from 'items'
 */
function load_elements(arg0){
    set = items[arg0];
    box_handle = $('.bottom_content');
    elements = '';

    //construct html for elements to be added
    for(i=0; i<set.length; i++){
        elements += '<div class="draggable"><img alt="' + set[i][0] + '" src="' + base_url + 'application/assets/images/items/' + set[i][1] + '.png" /></div>';
    }

    //clear whatever was in there
    box_handle.empty();

    // element parent container
    box_handle.html(elements);

    //assign draggable status
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 0,
        helper: 'clone'
    });
    loaded[arg0] = true;
    if(preloading){
        var prev = next_elements(-1);
        var next = next_elements(1);
        if(!loaded[prev]){
            preload(items[prev])
            loaded[prev] = true;
        }
        if(!loaded[next]){
            preload(items[next])
            loaded[prev] = true;
        }
    }

}

function next_elements(arg0){
    if((current_item_group + arg0) == -1){
        return 6;
    }else{
        return ((current_item_group + arg0) % 7);
    }
}
/*
 * Cycles through element groups presented in .bottom_content
-1 to the left 1 to the right
 */
function cycle_elements(arg0){

    if((current_item_group + arg0) == -1){
        current_item_group = 6;
    }else{
        current_item_group = ((current_item_group + arg0) % 7);
    }

    load_elements(current_item_group);
}

/*
 * Callback function on drop event for droppable
 * Determines position of dropped element in droppable
 */
function on_element_drop(event, ui){
    drop_area = $('#drop_area');
    element = ui.helper;

    //Find relative x/y position of element inside drop_area
    var x = Math.floor((element.offset().left - drop_area.offset().left) / drop_area.width() * 100);
    var y = Math.floor((element.offset().top - drop_area.offset().top) / drop_area.height() * 100); 

    //console.log(ui); return;

    //console.log(ui.draggable.context.className.indexOf('draggable_dropped'));

    if(ui.draggable.context.className.indexOf('draggable_dropped') == -1){
        if(global_positions.length >= 10)
            return;

        //record element position and id
        row = new Array(parseInt($(ui.draggable).find("img").attr('alt')),
                        x,
                        y);

        //Add copy of item to drop_area at same x/y position where it was dropped
        add_element_copy_to_div(row);

        add_element_copy_to_global_positions(row);

    }else{
        //Item has already been dropped and is being adjusted, update global_positions
        //update global_positions
        id = ui.draggable.context.id;
        update_global_positions(id, x, y);
    }
    //$('#countdown').html((10 - global_positions.length)+'');
    console.log(global_positions);
}

/*
 * Finds element in global_positions and updates x & y values
 */
function update_global_positions(id, newX, newY){

    image_id = global_positions[id][0];

    global_positions[id] = new Array(image_id, newX, newY);

    /*
    var old_array = global_positions[find_index(global_positions, index)];
    var new_array = new Array(old_array[0], newX, newY);

    //.splice(i,1,pos) -- remove 1 element at index i and replace with pos
    global_positions.splice(index,1,new_array);
    */
}

/*
 * Helper function, determines if element is already present in 'global_positions'
 * Replaces if present, adds otherwise
 */
function add_element_copy_to_global_positions(pos){

    global_positions.push(pos);

    /*
    var found = false;

    for(i=0;i<global_positions.length;i++){
        if(global_positions[i][0] == pos[0]){
            //.splice(i,1,pos) -- remove 1 element at index i and replace with pos
            global_positions.splice(i,1,pos);
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if(!found)
        global_positions.push(pos);
    */
}

/*
 * Helper function, adds a copy of the draggable that was dropped into the droppable
 * for user visualization 
 */
function add_element_copy_to_div(pos){
    drop_area = $('#drop_area');
    id = global_positions.length;

    console.log('id: ' + id);

    //Convert % x&y offsets into absolute pixel offsets based on div size
    x = Math.floor(drop_area.width() * (pos[1] / 100));
    y = Math.floor(drop_area.height() * (pos[2] / 100));

    /*------- Find filename of image that has been dropped ------*/
    index = find_index(items[current_item_group], pos[0]);
    filename = items[current_item_group][index][1];

    drop_area.append('<div style="position:absolute;" class="draggable_dropped" id="' +  id  + '"><img src="' + base_url + 'application/assets/images/items/' + filename  + '.png" /></div>');
    $('#'+id).css('left', x);
    $('#'+id).css('top', y);

    //Set the newly dropped element to draggable so it can be repositioned
    $('#'+id).draggable({
        stop:function(event, ui){
            if(!is_valid_position(ui)) //invalid drop
                delete_item(ui);
        }
    });
}

/*
 * deletes element from global_positions and #drop_area when user drops item outside #drop_area
 *  also adjusts id attributes of all items
 */
function delete_item(ui){
    id = ui.helper.context.id;
    $('#'+id).remove();

    global_positions.splice(id, 1);

    $('#drop_area div').each(function(index){
        if(parseInt($(this).attr('id')) > parseInt(id))
            $(this).attr('id', parseInt($(this).attr('id')) - 1);
    });

    console.log(global_positions);
}

/*
 * helper for add_element_copy_to_div
 */
function is_valid_position(ui){
    drop_area = $('#drop_area');
    element = ui.helper;

    //Find relative x/y position of element inside drop_area
    var x = Math.floor((element.offset().left - drop_area.offset().left) / drop_area.width() * 100);
    var y = Math.floor((element.offset().top - drop_area.offset().top) / drop_area.height() * 100);

    if( (x < -5)  || 
        (x > 105) ||
        (y < -5)  ||
        (y > 105))
        return false;
    return true;
}

/*
 * helper for add_element_copy_to_div
 */
function find_index(items, search_index){
    for(i=0; i < items.length; i++){
        if(items[i][0] == search_index)
            return i;
    }
}

/*
 * Convert global_position array to JSON and submit to server via ajax along with csrf_token
 */
function update_layout(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/projects/velcro/index.php/welcome/update_layout',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'layout_json' : $.toJSON(global_positions), 'ci_csrf_token' : $('input[name=ci_csrf_token]').val()},
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            //Redirect user to next page here...
            if(data == '1'){
                //alert('Layout successfully saved');
            }else{
                //alert('Layout save failed');
            }
            location.href = 'http://www.messageamplify.com/projects/velcro/index.php/welcome/create2';
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('error: '+jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

//End file 'dragdrop.js'
```

Comment: Sometimes IE errors are useless. can you post the code previous to this (please omit those line numbers...)

Comment: Did you try [Development Tools for IE](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359)?

Comment: @Ivan Nevostruev, yes I have downloaded the IE Development Toolbar, I'm using the console within that add-on. I have to say, it seems like a much more primitive console than what I get with Firebug in Firefox or Chrome's debugging/development features

Comment: @Casey Where are `drop_area` and `element` declared?

Comment: @Casey How is the event handler bound?

Comment: @Casey Try logging the `ui` argument. Is it defined?

Comment: Would it help if I just put up my entire javascript file? I can do that.

Comment: @Casey If it's a lot of code, consider [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @Sime Vidas, thanks for the tip. I simply posted it into the body of my question but I'll go check out pastebin now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
drop_area = $('#drop_area');
```

This line will ***always*** throw a error in IE. That's because in IE every element with id will be accessible through the global `window` object, in this case, `window.drop_area`. But the fact that `window` is a global object makes possible to access the object without the global, in this case, just `drop_area`.

So, the sentence `drop_area = $('#drop_area');` is not trying to assign a object to a variable, but is trying to **overwrite a element** reference with another object. This is the error you are seeing as a runtime exception.

To bypass this exception, you need to assign the jQuery object to a variable. To do this, you have two choices:

1. use a `var` statement to scope the variable inside the function that contains the code and hide the access to window.drop_area from the global, like `var drop_area = $('#drop_area');`, or
2. use another variable name, like `var dropArea = $('#drop_area');`

And, as a good advice, always give a scope to the variables you are using with `var` statement.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 has a built in debugger. Press F12, click the Script tab, click Start Debugging, and debug away.

Comment: @Craig M, I've actually been using this but unfortunately if I do a console.log(someobject); I can't really see anything useful about it. Whereas in FireFox and Chrome I can easily debug objects by drilling down and looking at their properties. I'm thinking my particular error is being caused by calling a property that IE7/8 might not support

Comment: Add a watch and you can look at objects the same as in Chrome or FF.

Comment: Who down voted this answer and why? This is correct. The question was not if the debugger is as good, simply 'how to'? Also write a debug function that is xbrowser compatible. function log() {
try {
console.log.apply( console, arguments );
} catch(e) {
try {
opera.postError.apply( opera, arguments );
} catch(e){
alert( Array.prototype.join.call( arguments, " " ) );
}
}
}

Comment: @Sime Vidas, I tried console.log(typeof ui), and I get: LOG: object  which is pretty much what I expect. I'm still not sure what could be causing this particular error however.

Comment: Like I already said, add a breakpoint and a watch on the variable in question and you can get that info you're after.

Comment: I just gave that a shot, looks like the problem is something to do with drop_area = $('#drop_area'); <-- any ideas? '#drop_area' is just a div and it works in other browsers

Comment: If you debug in IE9, change the browser and document modes to ie7/8 and do a console.log, you get the option to add what's returned to your "watch" list. You can then view the whole object.